# Using sanitizer to remove bad UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitize

I have written a small api in ruby on rails and I am getting some data from a [site](http://www.food2fork.com/about/api) but i have a problem. Instead of getting "Kahlúa" I am getting "Kahl&uacute;a" .
I have tried using a sanitizer but i cant figure out how to do it :/

This is my code :

```
<% full_sanitizer= Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new %>
<%= full_sanitizer.sanitize( link_to(course["title"], course["f2f_url"])) %>
```

I was thinking this is removen "ú" but it is only removing the link ;/
Can someone help me?

If you give me a MINUS pls comment and tell me what I did wrong so I can improve. Thanks :)

Comment: poz! what does "getting data from a site" mean? what does your original string contain? the question is not clear.

Comment: Hi, I am getting data using an API, I linked it now in the question :)

Comment: What result do you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: I want to get "Kahlúa" but instead I am getting "Kahl&uacute;a" :/

Comment: What you need is not sanitization, but rather HTML decoding. Take look at the other question. I believe, in your case, you will have to use `htmlentities` or similar library, as `CGI` does not cover these Unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you, Hvala :) I will try